# Navigation sprite not showing as background image

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if someone could explain why my navigational sprite isnt showing up next to my links. I have set the url and width so I am unsure what is going wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uZzBW/11/

```
.nav-sprite {
 background:url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the icons inline with the links, I would suggest something like this:

```
.nav-sprite {
  background: url('http://www.otlayi.com/web_images/content/free-doc-type-sprite-icons.jpg');
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You could also add `vertical-align: middle;` to better align it with the text.

Answer (score 2):

Spans are not block elements like divs - they are inline elements. So they essentially  "collapse". Adding height, width, and display:block will solve it. There are other methods too, but this is pretty straight forward.

```
width: 30px; 
display:block;
height:30px;
```

added to `.nav-sprite` exposes the sprite. I will let you position the final pixels/height/width.

see my fork http://jsfiddle.net/Hs8m5/

Comment: you probably want them set to `display: inline-block` so that they line up with your text.